# Mosquitto Dynamic Security Plugin fails creating dynamic-security.json

Tags: mosquitto

I get the following error when trying to create the dynamic-security file, but there is still memory in that path.

```
$ mosquitto_ctrl dynsec init dynamic-security.json user
New password for user: 
Reenter password for user: 
dynsec init: Out of memory.
Error: Out of memory.

$ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p3  433G  116G  295G  29% /
```

How could I debug this further? Thanks!

Comment: memory != disk space (`df -h .` shows disk space available not the amount of available memory)